# Ho do I use .htaccess/REGEX to forward to different URLs based on original URL format?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to get my head around how to conditionally forward a domain to a new domain based on the format of the original URL like this:

old-domain.co.uk -->  newdomain.co.uk/area/mytown

old-domain.co.uk/path-to-article --> newdomain.co.uk/path-to-article

The code below works fine for any URL that has a path after the domain, but obviously just forwards olddomain.co.uk to newdomain.co.uk

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So https://olddomain.co.uk/test/newpage will forward to https://newdomain.co.uk/test/newpage and that is great.

But https://olddomain.co.uk will forward to https://newdomain.co.uk which is not what I want, so I need to "trap" this if the original URL has no path after the domain and redirect this to a specific URL, not just the new domain.

Going round in circles trying to figure out the logic for this, so any help appreciated! I'm assuming that I need to specify somthing along the lines of "if the URL is an exact match then do this, if the URL has something after the domain then do this instead"

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if no URL has not a path (REQUEST_URI => /) AND the domain (HTTP_HOST) is [www.old-domain.co.uk](http://www.old-domain.co.uk) or old-domain.co.uk.
2. Check if URL has a path (REQUEST_URI != /) AND the domain (HTTP_HOST)is [www.old-domain.co.uk](http://www.old-domain.co.uk) or old-domain.co.uk.

```
# 1.
# old-domain.co.uk --> newdomain.co.uk/area/mytown
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule - https://newdomain.co.uk/area/mytown [R=301,L]

# 2.
# old-domain.co.uk/path-to-article --> newdomain.co.uk/path-to-article
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I  like the check for the for the www instead of having to do it on two lines....you learn something new every day!

Code works great with a small alteration on the last line of #1 - you need the ^(.*)$ I think?

Comment: Only if you want to match the whole path you can use `^(.*)$`. I have copied your example and used `^(.*)$`.  You can also write only `(.*)` if you want to match all.  But there is only a redirect, which is why you can use `-`. Why should you match something if you don't use the result?